# Invalid use of side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function

Tags: sql-server-2008, functions

I'm trying to create a scalar function that will return a delimited list from some sql that would be passed in.  Unfortuantly where I work the previous people responsible for the database thought it would be a good idea to put comma delimited id lists inside of some columns.  This function is the first step for me to rectify the problem without breaking the developers UI.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?  My code is below.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION fnSQLToDelimitedList ( @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delimiter NVARCHAR(3))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TEMPVALUES TABLE (VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)


INSERT INTO @TEMPVALUES (VALUE)
EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TEMPVALUES)
BEGIN

SET @VALUE = (SELECT TOP 1 value
                FROM @TEMPVALUES)
SET @OUTPUT = @OUTPUT + ' ' +  @VALUE + @Delimiter

DELETE FROM @TEMPVALUES WHERE VALUE = @VALUE
END

SET @OUTPUT = SUBSTRING(@OUTPUT,0, LEN(@OUTPUT) )

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @OUTPUT

END
GO
```

Comment: Functions on SQL Server are not the same as stored procedures, they have several limitations on the things that can be done. For example, you can't use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I have no idea what you're passing in using `@SQL` but there are also much better string splitting techniques out there: for a few examples and performance comparisons, see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings and http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up

Comment: Also instead of passing in delimited strings in the first place have a look at table-valued parameters: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Comment: Lamark - so I would want to use a stored procedure to accomplish this then it sounds like.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand - I'm looking to send in a SQL query as @SQL and return a delimited list of the results.

Comment: @Lumpy can you show an example of the SQL, an example of the output you expect, and explain why you need to do this using a function? Also please be sure to use `@` when replying to someone so they see the replies in their inbox (also be sure to spell people's name right - there is no `r` in `Lamak`).

Answer (score 0):

use this code to join rowset to delimited single value

sql,

use this code instead:

```
    DECLARE @IDs NVARCHAR(max)=''

    SELECT @IDs += ID +','
    FROM dbo.SomeTable

select @IDs
```

you can add where clause and design your query to return  rowset with CTE and UNION ALL